# Bing Maps WPF Control grey background in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I'm having a problem with Bing Maps WPF Control in just one particular customer.

The bing map logo is there and the kilometers scale too but the tiles are grey.

If I type an address to search, it will put a pushpin with the right latitude and longitude but the tiles still grey.

Is working fine everywhere else so the only difference that I can find is that the app is running on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

It's winform app with a WPF control.

The Bing Map Key is correct (checked 5 times!!).

Any ideas, suggestions, pointers?

Comment: It was down to the Proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured the Internet gateway not to proxy web traffic coming from the server and the maps feature of the app is working.